# 401 - unauthorized access : Auth0 and azure

Tags: javascript, azure, authentication, auth0, azure-sql-database

I have connected my Database to auth0 and when I try the connection is returns 401 unauthorized access. I have allowed auth into my firewall and the password is correct. How come it is returning this error when searching for username and password?

**More info**

in my easy tables I made them authenticated access only, do I have to do something to get around this?

```
function login(email, password, callback) {
      //this example uses the "tedious" library
      //more info here: http://pekim.github.io/tedious/index.html
      var Connection = require('tedious@1.11.0').Connection;
      var Request = require('tedious@1.11.0').Request;
      var TYPES = require('tedious@1.11.0').TYPES;

      var connection = new Connection({
        userName: 'username',
        password: 'pass',
        server: 'server',
        options: {
          database: 'db',
          encrypt: true,
          rowCollectionOnRequestCompletion: true
        }
      });

      var query = "SELECT Id, Email, Password " +
        "FROM user WHERE Email = @Email";

      connection.on('debug', function (text) {
        // Uncomment next line in order to enable debugging messages
        // console.log(text);
      }).on('errorMessage', function (text) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(text, null, 2));
        return callback(text);
      }).on('infoMessage', function (text) {
        // Uncomment next line in order to enable information messages
        // console.log(JSON.stringify(text, null, 2));
      });

      connection.on('connect', function (err) {
        if (err) { return callback(err); }

        var request = new Request(query, function (err, rowCount, rows) {
          if (err) {
            callback(new Error(err));
          } else if (rowCount < 1) {
            callback(new WrongUsernameOrPasswordError(email));
          } else {
            bcrypt.compare(password, rows[0][2].value, function (err, isValid) {
              if (err) { callback(new Error(err)); }
              else if (!isValid) { callback(new WrongUsernameOrPasswordError(email)); }
              else {
                callback(null, {
                  user_id: rows[0][0].value,
                  email: rows[0][1].value
                });
              }
            });
          }
        });

        request.addParameter('Email', TYPES.VarChar, email);
        connection.execSql(request);
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using Azure Mobile App, which included [the Node.js server SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-node) for your app. Then you don't need to install `tedious` to work with Azure SQL database. The SDK has already wrapped up [`mssql`](https://github.com/patriksimek/node-mssql) to do this. So basically you can use [this code sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-node/blob/master/samples/custom-api-sql-stmt/api/completeall.js) to connect your database.

```
var api = {
    // an example of executing a SQL statement directly
    get: (request, response, next) => {
        var query = {
            sql: 'UPDATE TodoItem SET complete = @completed',
            parameters: [
                { name: 'completed', value: request.query.completed }
            ]
        };

        request.azureMobile.data.execute(query)
            .then(function (results) {
                response.json(results);
            });
    },
    // an example of executing a stored procedure
    post: (request, response, next) => {
        var query = {
            sql: 'EXEC completeAllStoredProcedure @completed',
            parameters: [
                { name: 'completed', value: request.query.completed }
            ]
        };

        request.azureMobile.data.execute(query)
            .then(function (results) {
                response.json(results);
            });
    }
};

module.exports = api;
```

For more information, please refer to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-node-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk#a-nametableoperationsatable-operations).